# create XML file using bash script

Tags: linux, bash, sed, echo, xml

I want create simple xml file using bash script ( not with dom )

but when I set value in the line then  **echo** print the $lorem word and not the val

**lorem=LOL**

```
echo '<root><foo a="b">$lorem</foo><bar value="ipsum" /></root>' >> $MY_XML
```

I also try this

```
echo '<root><foo a="b">\$lorem</foo><bar value="ipsum" /></root>' >> $MY_XML

echo '<root><foo a="b">"$lorem"</foo><bar value="ipsum" /></root>' >> $MY_XML

echo '<root><foo a="b">\"$lorem\"</foo><bar value="ipsum" /></root>' >> $MY_XML
```

but all these print the exactly the line and not the val

please advice how to print the val $lorem ? as the following example

```
 <root><foo a="b">LOL</foo><bar value="ipsum" /></root>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Print the line on this way:

```
echo '<root><foo a="b">'"$lorem"'</foo><bar value="ipsum" /></root>' >> "$MY_XML"
```

This is need because single quotes deny shell interpreter from replace environment variables inside

Answer (score 5):

Use in-line document with cat

```
cat >destfile <<EOF
<your ZML here...where $vas expand happly>
but the rest remain as is
EOF
```

I used it in a lot of scripts.
Consider also [envsubst command to restrict variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/294378/replacing-only-specific-variables-with-envsubst) you can use in the in-line document.

Answer (score 4):

Frustratingly perhaps, one of the combinations you omitted would have worked:

```
echo "<root><foo a=\"b\">$lorem</foo><bar value=\"ipsum\" /></root>" >> $MY_XML
```

Single quotes leave everything exactly as you type it. Escaping with `\` will not work. Double quotes will evaluate the string. Inside double quotes you can use `\` to escape specific characters (including the double-quote character itself).

You could also combine parts of the string that are quoted in different ways. Here, `$lorem` remains double-quoted but the rest of the string is surrounded with single quotes:

```
echo '<root><foo a="b">'"$lorem"'</foo><bar value="ipsum" /></root>' >> $MY_XML
```

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that you are using your variable in a single-quoted string.  The shell will never expand variables in single quoted strings.

Another issue is that the value in `$lorem` would not be properly XML encoded, so a value like `<!--` would mess up the XML document and make it unparseable.

Instead, use `jo` from https://jpmens.net/2016/03/05/a-shell-command-to-create-json-jo/ to create a JSON document and the `yq` tool from https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/ to convert this to XML:

```bash
$ lorem=LOL
$ jo -p 'foo[@a]'=b 'foo[#text]'="$lorem" 'bar[@value]'=ipsum
{
   "foo": {
      "@a": "b",
      "#text": "LOL"
   },
   "bar": {
      "@value": "ipsum"
   }
}
```

Then pass this through `yq -x --xml-root=root .` to convert to XML and wrap it in a top-level root node called `root`.  Keys starting with `@` will be turned into node attributes, and the value of the `#text` key will be turned into the node's value.

```bash
$ jo 'foo[@a]'=b 'foo[#text]'="$lorem" 'bar[@value]'=ipsum | yq -x --xml-root=root .
<root>
  <foo a="b">LOL</foo>
  <bar value="ipsum"></bar>
</root>
```

With the value `<!--` in `$lorem`:

```bash
$ lorem='<!--'
$ jo 'foo[@a]'=b 'foo[#text]'="$lorem" 'bar[@value]'=ipsum | yq -x --xml-root=root .
<root>
  <foo a="b">&lt;!--</foo>
  <bar value="ipsum"></bar>
</root>
```

Or, with the literal value `$lorem` in the variable:

```bash
$ lorem='$lorem'
$ jo 'foo[@a]'=b 'foo[#text]'="$lorem" 'bar[@value]'=ipsum | yq -x --xml-root=root .
<root>
  <foo a="b">$lorem</foo>
  <bar value="ipsum"></bar>
</root>
```

Comment: `yq --help` print nothing about xml support (but mentioned commands works). The [recommended way](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq?tab=readme-ov-file#xml-support) to use xml related functionality is via `xq` executable.

Answer (score 0):

When you interpolate values into XML template make sure to escape special characters:

```
escape() {
    local val
    val=$1
    val=${val//&/&amp;}
    val=${val//</&lt;}
    val=${val//>/&gt;}
    val=${val//\'/&apos;}
    val=${val//\"/&quot;}
    printf %s "$val"
}

lorem="\"Foo\" & 'Bar' & <Baz>"

cat << EOF
<root><foo a="b">$(escape "$lorem")</foo><bar value="ipsum" /></root>
EOF
```

Comment: You can replace your `escape` function with `xmlstarlet escape`.