# Replacing only specific variables with envsubst

Tags: shell, environment-variables

I'm trying to perform environment variable replacement through `envsubst`, but I want to only replace specific variables.

From the docs I should be able to tell `envsubst` to only replace certain variables but I'm failing to be able to do that.

For example, if I have a file containing:

```
VAR_1=${VAR_1}
VAR_2=${VAR_2}
```

how should I execute `envsubst` so that it only replaces the reference to `${VAR_1}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before calling `envsubst` you should use export using single quotes to get back `VAR_1` modified. As in:

```
export VAR_1='somevalue'
```

For more details, please see:

[How to substitute shell variables in complex text files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14155596/how-to-substitute-shell-variables-in-complex-text-files)

Comment: Correct answer is below

Comment: @JoãoAngelo Would you clarify why this was marked has the correct one over the other answer? For me it seems more appropriate asking the original asker.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro your answer will replace all variables (not only specific variables). all patterns like `$varname` will be evaluated (not only the variables you're targetting).

Comment: check this case, https://serverfault.com/questions/577370/how-can-i-use-environment-variables-in-nginx-conf#comment952176_755541

Comment: @Craig There is no "below" on stack overflow - answers change order depending on various factors. Please link to the actual answer.

Comment: This is not the correct answer. This will lead to any undefined vriable being replaced with an empty string. The correct answer is by @don_crissti

Answer (score 288):

Per the man page:

```
envsubst [OPTION] [SHELL-FORMAT]
```

> If a SHELL-FORMAT is  given,  only those  environment  variables  that
> are referenced in SHELL-FORMAT are substituted; otherwise all
> environment variables references occurring in standard input are
> substituted.

Where SHELL-FORMAT strings are *["strings with references to shell variables in the form `$variable` or `${variable}`[...] The variable names must consist solely of alphanumeric or underscore ASCII characters, not start with a digit and be nonempty; otherwise such a variable reference is ignored."](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#sh_002dformat)*.

---

Note that the format `${VAR:-default}` is not supported. I mentioned [HERE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/294840) some alternatives that support it along with other features.

---

Anyway, back to `gettext`  `envsubst`:
So, one has to pass the respective variables names to `envsubst` in a shell format string (obviously, they need to be escaped/quoted so as to be passed literally to `envsubst`). Example:

input file e.g. `infile`:

```
VAR1=${VAR1}
VAR2=${VAR2}
VAR3=${VAR3}
```

and some values like

```
export  VAR1="one" VAR2="two" VAR3="three"
```

then running

```
envsubst '${VAR1} ${VAR3}' <infile
```

or

```
envsubst '${VAR1},${VAR3}' <infile
```

or

```
envsubst '${VAR1}
${VAR3}' <infile
```

outputs

```
VAR1=one
VAR2=${VAR2}
VAR3=three
```

Or, if you prefer backslash:

```
envsubst \$VAR1,\$VAR2 <infile
```

produces

```
VAR1=one
VAR2=two
VAR3=${VAR3}
```

To avoid leakage of the custom-set variables into the executing shell's environment, instead of exporting these variables, [some shells such as *Bash* allow prefixing the command with *variable assignments*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Simple-Command-Expansion.html). The values assigned in this way will only be used for the command's execution, and don't affect the shell environment afterwards:

```
export VAR1="one" VAR2="two" VAR3="three"

# ...

VAR1="number 1" VAR3="numero 3" envsubst '${VAR1} ${VAR3}' <infile

# output:
# VAR1=number 1
# VAR2=${VAR2}
# VAR3=numero 3

echo "VAR1=${VAR1}"
echo "VAR2=${VAR2}"
echo "VAR3=${VAR3}"
# output shows that the original environment was preserved:
# VAR1=one
# VAR2=two
# VAR3=three
```

Comment: why is this not the accepted answer?

Comment: Yes this is the right answer!

Comment: If you know a variable prefix to use to limit the variables that can be substituted:
`envsubst "$(printf '${%s} ' ${!PREFIX*})"  < infile`

Comment: Or if you have a list of them in `SUBST_VARS` then: `envsubst "$(printf '${%s} ' $SUBST_VARS)" < infile`

Comment: This answer ALSO substitutes an empty string for variables present that are not set. As opposed to ONLY replacing the specific variables.

Comment: Thank you very, very much for explaining the use of "SHELL-FORMAT".  I didn't see that in any version of the envsubst manpage or in its `--help` output.

Comment: If you want to replace all the *exported* items use: `envsubst "$(compgen -e | awk '$0="${"$0"}"')" < infile`.

Comment: You can use the `-v` or `--variables` flag to output the variables given in SHELL-FORMAT (to verify that your syntax is correct): e.g. `envsubst -v '${VAR1} $VAR2 NOVAR'`.

Comment: Overall the is a great answer with great comments! And I like to be able to write human kindness into comments!!!

Comment: On a Mac, I get `VAR1=one
VAR2=two
VAR3=three`

Comment: @SamLiddicott Great tips, to complete your suggestion, the SUBST_VARS must be defined as `SUBST_VARS='$MYVAR1 $MYVAR2 $ANOTHER_varX'

Comment: is it possible to set the variables and invoke envsubst in single command?

Comment: For anyone having an issue using docker-compose, you will need to use two dollar `envsubst '$$DOCKER_NGINX_LOCAL_IP' < infile`

Answer (score 3):

Although related to docker, the utility `envplate` should do the job https://github.com/kreuzwerker/envplate

From the readme:

> Trivial templating for configuration files using environment keys. References to such keys are declared in arbitrary config files either as:
>
> ${key} or
>
> ${key:-default value}

gnutext's envsubst only replaces `${key}`; if missing is replaced by `''`.

Comment: Another `envsubst` implementation, this time in golang: https://github.com/drone/envsubst

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately 'export' is mandatory, otherwise it won't work. Here is an example.

First, the input file. Note that I only want to change NGINX_HOST and NGINX_PORT and don't want to touch other variables in the input file such as '$uri'.

```
$ egrep 'server_name|listen|try_files' nginx-default.conf.template 
  server_name ${NGINX_HOST};
  listen ${NGINX_PORT};
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
```

Now the empty variables:

```
$ echo ${NGINX_HOST}

$ echo ${NGINX_PORT}
```

Set default values to these variables:

```
$ NGINX_HOST=${NGINX_HOST:-localhost}
$ NGINX_PORT=${NGINX_PORT:-80}
$ echo ${NGINX_HOST}
localhost
$ echo ${NGINX_PORT}
80
```

Try to use envsubst:

```
$ envsubst \
    '${NGINX_HOST} ${NGINX_PORT}' \
    < nginx-default.conf.template \
    | egrep 'server_name|listen|try_files' 
    
  server_name ;
  listen ;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
```

As you can see, it did not work. The variables must be 'export'-ed for this to work. Here is the second run:

```
$ export NGINX_HOST=${NGINX_HOST:-localhost}
$ export NGINX_PORT=${NGINX_PORT:-80}

$ envsubst   '${NGINX_HOST} ${NGINX_PORT}' <  nginx-default.conf.template | egrep 'server_name|listen|try_files' 

  server_name localhost;
  listen 80;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
```

As you can see, now it worked. Hope it helps others.

Comment: This is like a car user’s manual saying “This car must be used on a solid surface in a gravitational field.   It doesn’t work in water, or when in free-fall or in outer space.”   In other words, everybody knows this.

Comment: The question is rather: How to avoid replacing `$uri` in the file if there is an `uri` environment variable in the current environment.

Comment: G-Man... this is a site where people who don't understand things come to learn about them. Just because you understand unix well enough to know the export is required does not mean that everyone will understand this.  People who drive all the time know that to signal left you move the lever down, and up for right... but people who are still learning to drive don't understand this, and we should be more patient, even if YOU already understand it perfectly.