# replace placeholders in file with the actual environment variables using sed

Tags: sed

I have a template file like this:

```
export const environment = {
  api: {
    url: '$API_URL',
    key: '$API_KEY',
  }
}
```

and I was trying to replace the actual placeholder values like this:

```
sed 's/$\([A-Z_]*\)/$(\1)/g' ./input.ts ./output.ts
```

So I wanted it to replace the placeholders with the actual values of the environment variables but when I run the above script I get:

```
export const environment = {
  api: {
    url: '$(API_URL)',
    key: '$(API_KEY)'
  }
}
```

So given these vars:

```
export API_URL=someurl
export API_KEY=key
```

I would expect the output to be:

```
export const environment = {
  api: {
    url: 'someurl',
    key: 'key'
  }
}
```

I can get this working with explicitly naming the variables:

```
sed -e 's|$API_URL|'$API_URL'|g
        s|$API_KEY|'$API_KEY'|g
        ./in.ts > ./out.ts
```

But is there a way to do this dynamically?

Comment: Related: [Replace environment variables in a file with their actual values?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/294835/replace-environment-variables-in-a-file-with-their-actual-values)

Comment: they are brought in from an external program.  It is an azure pipeline

Comment: I have updated the question, please let me know if there is anything else I can do

Comment: it is part of the output, I just want the $API_** placeholders replaced with the actual values of an environment variable that is the exact same name

Comment: I have updated the question