# Variable substitution from/to file

Tags: variable-substitution

How do I replace placeholders in a file with variables from another file? (Like docker-compose is doing it.)

I found many articles about single variable replacements or replacement by environment variables but not file to file.

.env file

```
name=John
time='10:00'
```

Content file

```
Hello "${name}"! I wait for u since ${time}.
```

Output file:

```
Hello "John"! I wait for u since 10:00.
```

Edit: Note that I also want to keep the `"` in the file.

Edit2:
I ended up using the solution from @steeldriver. This is what I use now in my script:

```bsh
# Make copy of the template folder (containing scripts and `.env` file)
cp -r templates .templates

# Replace environment variables in all files of the folder
set -a
for file in $(find .templates -type f)
do
    . ./.env && envsubst < $file > $file.tmp && mv $file.tmp $file
done
set +a

# create output directory
mkdir -p $HOME/output/

# copy if new or modified
rsync -raz .templates/. $HOME/output/

# remove temp folder
rm -r .templates
```

Comment: Consider also moustache, and other templating languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `envsubst`

```
set -a
. ./.env && envsubst < content
set +a
```

The `set -a` / `set +a` turn on / off automatic export of created/modified variables.

Answer (score 0):

Found a working solution in [Replace environment variables in a file with their actual values?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/294837/56107)

`(. .env && eval "echo \"$(cat config.xml)\"")`

Edit: This solution removes also `"` marks in the files. Thats not what I wanted.

Comment: That would potentially run any command after a `"` and a `;` (or newline, etc.) in the XML file. Better to use `envsubst`.

Comment: @Kusalananda can u give an example? I also noticed that `"` will be removed from my file with this command :(