# How to expand array elements containing variable?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ksh

I have an array in which every element may contain another variable. The array assignment is from a file as follows:

```
FILE_CLEANUP_DIR_ARR=($(cat cleanup.list | sed '/^[[:blank:]]*$/d' | sed '/^[#]/d'))
```

How can I restore the aray with the expanded variables.

`TARGET_DIR=/SOMEROOTDIR`

`FILE_CLEANUP_DIR_ARR[0]` has value literally as `$TARGET_DIR/SOMESUBDIR0`

`FILE_CLEANUP_DIR_ARR[1]` has value literally as `$TARGET_DIR/SOMESUBDIR1`

How can I restore this FILE_CLEANUP_DIR_ARR to expanded variables as follows.

`FILE_CLEANUP_DIR_ARR[0] = /SOMEROOTDIR/SOMESUBDIR0`

`FILE_CLEANUP_DIR_ARR[1] = /SOMEROOTDIR/SOMESUBDIR1`

Sample code. Not working.

```
i=0
for CDIR in "${FILE_CLEANUP_DIR_ARR[@]}";
do
FILE_CLEANUP_DIR_ARR[i]="$CDIR"
((i++))
done
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you have shell code in the array's elements instead of expanded strings? It seems the easiest way to solve this would be to expand the values at the time of assigning them to the array from the start.

Comment: I am actually reading this array by taking entries from a flat file, that has the literal values as $TARGET_DIR and the assignment is as follows `FILE_CLEANUP_DIR_ARR=($(cat cleanup.list |  sed '/^[[:blank:]]*$/d' | sed '/^[#]/d'))`

Comment: I added that useful information to the question ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expand the variables when reading the input using [`envsubst`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/294835/replace-environment-variables-in-a-file-with-their-actual-values):

```
export TARGET_DIR=/some/path/
FILE_CLEANUP_DIR_ARR=($(awk '!/^ *#/ && NF' global_file_transfer_cleanup.list | envsubst))
```

(`awk` part [via](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17396799/7365127).)

---

Bad alternative for this would be using `eval`:

```
FILE_CLEANUP_DIR_ARR[i]=$(eval printf '%s' "$CDIR")
```

Comment: Thank You. The approach with awk is working. I am also checking if I can pipe another sed and replace literal variable.