# how do I get my code to use the value of the $HOME variable?

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

I'm trying to put together a generic script that will check the existence of several key directories for various users on different servers. Additionally, I want to leverage each user's $HOME variable.

For eg, let's say this were true:

- on server 1: jdoe's home is /home/jdoe
- on server 2: jdoe's home is /opt/jdoe2
- server 3 hasn't been built yet; we won't know where they build his $HOME until the server is built.
- on server 4: mysql's home is /opt/home/mysql

This is what I have for my important directories (ordered from most to least impt):

```
$ cat mylist.txt
$HOME/most_impt_dir1
$HOME/most_impt_dir2
$HOME/most_impt_dir3
$HOME/misc
$HOME/junk
```

...I want to find the most impt dir owned by this user.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
for i in `cat mylist.txt`
do

  if [[ -O $i ]] && [[ -d $i ]]; then
    echo "found it: $i"
    break
  else
    echo "$i is not it."
  fi

done
```

The above code does not work for anything in my list because it is literally checking for dirs beginning with `$HOME`. How do I get my code to use the value of the user's `$HOME` variable?

Comment: You may find `envsubst` helpful - see for example [Replace environment variables in a file with their actual values?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/294835/replace-environment-variables-in-a-file-with-their-actual-values)

Comment: Thanks steeldriver!!! Never heard of that utilty. Got it to work using your tip:

Comment: for i in `cat mylist.txt`

do

  i=$(echo $j | envsubst)
  if [[ -O $i ]] && [[ -d $i ]]; then
    echo "found it: $i (ie, $j)"
    break
  else
    echo "$i is not it."
  fi

done

Comment: I'd actually suggest running `envsubst` on the whole file - see answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `envsubst` - replacing your `for/cat` loop with a `while/read` loop for the reasons discussed here:

- [Reading lines from a file with bash: for vs. while](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24260/reading-lines-from-a-file-with-bash-for-vs-while)

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r i
do

  if [[ -O $i ]] && [[ -d $i ]]; then
    echo "found it: $i"
    break
  else
    echo "$i is not it."
  fi

done < <(envsubst < mylist.txt)
```

See also

- [Replace environment variables in a file with their actual values?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/294835/replace-environment-variables-in-a-file-with-their-actual-values)

Answer (score 0):

Keep `$HOME` out of your file, and use it in your script. For example

```
$ cat mylist.txt
most_impt_dir1
most_impt_dir2
most_impt_dir3
misc
junk
```

Then:

```
while IFS= read -r i;
do
     dir=$HOME/$i
     if [[ -O $dir ]] ...
     ...
     fi
done < mylist.txt
```

---

Another option, given you're using bash, is to keep the list as a bash array, and source the file to get the list:

```
$ cat mylist.txt
dirs=(
"$HOME/most_impt_dir1"
"$HOME/most_impt_dir2"
"$HOME/most_impt_dir3"
"$HOME/misc"
"$HOME/junk"
)
```

Then the script will be like:

```
source ./mylist.txt
for dir in "${dirs[@]}"
do
    if [[ -O $dir ...
    ...
    fi
done
```