# Script using data/input which contains variable names

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable, eval

So I have a file "Directories.dat" that contains a list of directories for a script to read that runs on multiple machines. Due to this, the list of directories in the file is often defined with variables such as

```
#Directories.Dat
/home/$USER
$WORKDIR
$APPDIR
...etc
```

However, when the script runs through the file Directories.dat , $line ends up being set to `/home/$USER` rather than `/home/myuser`

```
#!/bin/bash
#myscript.sh
for line in $(cat Directories.dat) 
do 
SomeCommand $line
done
```

Should I not use `cat`?
Is `eval` the only suitable function for doing this?
example `SomeCommand $(eval echo $line) #DangerZone`
or are there other methods to read the lines within the Directories.dat file and show the variables as their stored values?

Comment: For *environment* variables, there's `envsubst` - see for example [how do I get my code to use the value of the $HOME variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/554333/how-do-i-get-my-code-to-use-the-value-of-the-home-variable)

Comment: *tears of joy* I think this will work. As long as I have sourced all the appropriate files. oh boy

Comment: yep, worked like a charm. Holy hell man thank you

Answer (score 0):

Moved from the question

```
#!/bin/bash
source bashrc.sh mysources.sh
#myscript.sh
for line in $(cat Directories.dat) 
do 
SomeCommand $(echo $line | envsubst)
done
```

Comment: NB. This is not robust code: it will break if any directory name contains a space

Comment: ... I'd suggest `envsubst < Directories.dat | while IFS= read -r line; do SomeCommand "$line"; done`