# Expand environment variable from JSON file

Tags: environment-variables, jq

I have a JSON file which contains the following (amongst other properties):

```
{
  "environment": "$USER"
}
```

I am extracting that value using `jq` like so:

```
ENVIRONMENT="$(jq -r '.environment' "properties.json")"
```

I want the value of `ENVIRONMENT` to be my username, **not** the string `$USER` - is this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Option 1: Just read variable by name

`bash` allows having variables that reference variables, example:

```
REF='USER'  # or get it from JSON
echo "${!REF}"
# prints current username
```

So you can write this:

```
ENVIRONMENT_REF="$(jq -r '.environment' "properties.json")"
ENVIRONMENT="${!ENVIRONMENT_REF}"
```

JSON contents:

```
"environment": "USER"
```

---

## Option 2: Full shell expansion

Other option, maybe better (but **definitely NOT secure**) is using `eval`:

```
ENVIRONMENT="$(eval "echo $(jq -r '.environment' "properties.json")")"
```

Note that this is **not secure** and malicious code can be inserted to the JSON file. What malicious code? Let's look into this `properties.json` file:

```
{
    "environment": "$(rm some_file)" 
}
```

The shell will `eval`uate this code:

```
echo $(rm some_file)
```

… and the file named `some_file` will be deleted. As you can see, depending on the command entered there, you can cause very serious damage.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had come across option 1 but was missing the key part that the value in the JSON file must not have the `$` symbol. Thanks for providing two options as well, and so quickly!

Comment: @StuartLeyland-Cole, if you think this is the correct answer, click the **√** icon on the left side.

Comment: @jiwopene and my thanks for the edit pointing out that `eval` is a security risk. It makes me feel better about upvoting :) Note that the system [doesn't allow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/50703/203101) the asker to accept an answer in the first 15 minutes after posting, so Stuart cannot accept yet.

Comment: @terdon, added example of malicious code.

Answer (score 10):

`jq` provides access to its environment via a `$ENV` object - similar to perl's `$ENV` hash or awk's `ENVIRON` associative array. So for example assuming (as suggested by the accepted answer) your properties.json file looks like

```
{
  "environment": "USER"
}
```

then you can do

```
$ environment="$(jq -r '$ENV[.environment]' properties.json)"
$ echo "$environment"
steeldriver
```

(best to avoid ALLCAPS for your shell variables). If your file looks like

```
{
  "environment": "$USER"
}
```

including the shell-expansion `$` then you can use the same method after removing the `$`:

```
environment="$(jq -r '$ENV[.environment | sub("^\\$";"")]' properties.json)"
```

Alternatively, you could pipe the result of a simple lookup through the external `envsubst` command:

```
$ environment="$(jq -r '.environment' properties.json | envsubst)"
$ echo "$environment"
steeldriver
```

See for example [Replace environment variables in a file with their actual values?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/294835/replace-environment-variables-in-a-file-with-their-actual-values)

Answer (score 1):

This is just a slight re-write of
[one of the other answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/636602).

In a Linux terminal, create a local folder:

```
$ mkdir -p ~/unix.se/jq/ && cd ~/unix.se/jq/
```

Create the file `properties.json`:

```
$ echo '{"environment":"USER"}'>properties.json && cat properties.json
{"environment":"USER"}
```

A side note - pretty formatting with `jq`:

```
$ jq '.' properties.json
{
  "environment": "USER"
}
```

Use the value of the JSON key `environment`, to
set a new environment variable and show its contents: <sup>1</sup>

```
$ JQ_USER=$(jq -r '$ENV[.environment]' properties.json) && echo $JQ_USER
tedly
```

So far so good, but the problem is that I have been lying.(!) - The
`properties.json` file does not look *quite* as above, as it has a dollar
sign in front of `USER`, like so:

```
$ echo '{"environment":"$USER"}'>properties.json && cat properties.json
{"environment":"$USER"}
```

By getting rid of that disturbing dollar sign, for example by substituting the
empty string for it, we can get back to the already working solution:

```
$ JQ_USER=$(jq -r '$ENV[.environment | sub("\\$";"")]' properties.json)
echo $JQ_USER
tedly
```

---

<sup>1</sup> When I first ran this, I got an error message starting with
`jq: error: ENV/0 is not defined at <top-level>`.
It turns out that `$ENV[]` [requires version 1.6](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#$ENV,env) (or later) of `jq`.

Answer (score 0):

One way can be as follows

```
ENVIRONMENT=$(printenv $(jq -r '.environment' properties.json |
cut -c2-))
```