# How to replace variable strings in a file?

Tags: shell, template

I have a file with variables in it like below, however I want to use this file as a template and replace the variables with its actual value.

Is there a way to read the file contents and evaluate the variables?

```
#my script
template=$(cat script.template)
MY_VAR="my_data"
echo $template
```

The above script should read the below file, and replace `MY_VAR` with the string `my_data`

```
# script.template
export MY_VAR=${MY_VAR}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this with bash?

```
# expected output
export MY_VAR=my data
```

Comment: Related: [Replacing only specific variables with envsubst](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/294378/170373)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, use envsubst

It's part of GNU get text

```
envsubst < source > destination
```