# Replace environment variables in text if they exist

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I know that `envsubst` replaces declared environment variables in the input.

```
$ echo 'Hello $USER' | envsubst
Hello myusername
```

What I want is a way to replace the environment variable if it exists otherwise `envsusbst` (or any other command), leaves the variable string as it is. What I get is:

```
$ echo 'Hello $USER $UNDEFINED_VARIABLE' | envsubst
Hello myusername
```

What I want is:

```
$ echo 'Hello $USER $UNDEFINED_VARIABLE' | somecommand
Hello myusername $UNDEFINED_VARIABLE
```

Comment: `envsubst "$(compgen -e | awk '$0="${"$0"}"')"` works for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It you pass an argument like `$USER$PATH` to `envsubst`, then it expands only those variables that are referenced in that argument.

So one way could be to pass it all the currently defined environment variables in that format. With `zsh`:

```
echo 'Hello $USER ${USER} $UNDEFINED_VARIABLE' |
  envsubst \$${(kj:$:)parameters[(R)*export*]}
```

- `$parameters` is a special associative array that maps variable names to their type
- `$parameters[(R)*export*]` expands to all the elements of the associative array whose value contains `export`.
- with the `k` parameter expansion flag, the *key* instead of the value is returned
- `j:$:` joins those elements with `$` in between, and we add one at the start.

With other shells, you can always revert to `perl` to get that list:

```
echo 'Hello $USER ${USER} $UNDEFINED_VARIABLE' |
  envsubst "$(perl -e 'print "\$$_" for grep /^[_a-zA-Z]\w*$/, keys %ENV')"
```

Beware both disclose your environment variable *names* in the output of `ps`.

Instead, you could also do the whole thing in `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's{(?|\$\{([_a-zA-Z]\w*)\}|\$([_a-zA-Z]\w*))}{$ENV{$1}//$&}ge'
```

Beware it has the same *limitations* as `envsubst` in that [it won't expand things like `${VAR:-x}`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/sh_002dformat.html) and would expand `$HOME` in things like `\$HOME` or `$$HOME` which a shell wouldn't.

Comment: This does not seem to work in my case. `unset UNDEFINED_VARIABLE; echo 'Hello $USER ${USER} $UNDEFINED_VARIABLE' | envsubst \$${(kj:$:)parameters[(R)*export*]};` outputs `Hello chris chris `.

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski, what's your version of `zsh` and `envsubst`? I can't reproduce with `zsh` 5.8 and `envsubst` from gettext 0.21 on Debian here.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `env` to see all currently defined environment variables and then use that list to only replace those. (The man page isn't very clear on that, but see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/294400/3929) for elucidation.)

```
echo 'Hello $USER $UNKNOWN' | envsubst "$(env | cut -d= -f1 | sed -e 's/^/$/')"
```

(The output of `env` lists the values of the variables as well, but `envsubst` also wants to see a leading `$`, so we can't just use `cut -d= -f1` on its own, unfortunately. You could use a single `sed` to do `cut`'s job as well, see previous revision, but I prefer the clarity of `cut` over a tiny performance gain.)

Comment: That assumes none of the env variables names or values contain newline characters (and names don't contain `$` characters)