# Can you explain this inner working of this printf command in bash?

Tags: bash, printf, subshell

I stumbled onto the question [Replacing only specific variables with envsubst](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/294378/replacing-only-specific-variables-with-envsubst) and in one of the [comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/294378/replacing-only-specific-variables-with-envsubst#comment912116_294400) was this shell example:

```
envsubst "$(printf '${%s} ' ${!PREFIX*})" < infile
```

See the original question for the full background, but in essence it is telling envsubst to replace only those environment variables that begin with the string "PREFIX".

But how is this working? Can someone explain the different "steps" that are involved? Is the infile read first? And what part is doing the grep/find kind of thing, so it can use the input from the file? Is the argument "${!PREFIX*}" some kind of regex? And is there some sub-shell magic being done here?

In order to try understanding it better, I created my own infile with this content:

```
1: ${VAR1}
2: ${VAR2}
3: ${VAR3}
4: ${PREFIX_1}
5: ${PREFIX_2}
6: ${PREFIX_3} ?
7: ${PREFIX_4} + ${PREFIX_5}
8: ${VAR4}
9: bla bla bla
```

I then replaced the envsubst with echo, resulting in this line:

```
echo "$(printf '${%s} ' ${!PREFIX*})" < infile
```

And this result:

```
${PREFIX_1}
```

So it works, but only for the first match. What am I doing wrong? I expected the output to contain all the "PREFIX_" variables 1 to 5. Maybe I messed up when I replaced envsubst with echo? If so, how can I see what stuff is sent to envsubst?

Comment: To see what it does, try `echo ${!PREFIX*}` and `printf '${%s} ' ${!PREFIX*}`, then e.g. `echo ${!P*}` and `printf '${%s} ' ${!P*}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`${!prefix_*}` is a Bash feature that expands to the names of all shell variables that start with `prefix_`. The `printf` in the command substitution then prints them inside braces (it repeats the format string as many times as necessary).

```
$ prefix_foo=1 prefix_bar=2
$ printf '${%s}\n' ${!prefix_*}
${prefix_bar}
${prefix_foo}
```

Because of the command substitution, they get dropped on `envsubst`'s command line. There's word splitting involved in both the `${!prefix_*}` expansion and the result of the command substitution, but it doesn't matter <sub>with the default `IFS`</sub> since variable names can't contain whitespace or glob characters.

> ```
> echo "$(printf '${%s} ' ${!PREFIX*})" < infile
> ```

Here, the contents of `infile` don't matter, since `echo` doesn't read anything from stdin. That will just print the names of the variables starting with `PREFIX`.

Comment: @steeldriver, yes, exactly.

Comment: Great answer! This explains why I got the PREFIX_1 one printed, because I had set it as an environment variable in an earlier test (that I had forgotten about). I thought that the only thing that did anything regarding environment variables was the envsubst command, and by replacing it with echo I thought it only used the file as input, not environment variables.